# Building own callstack

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to intercept all calls to my library at a single point and share a customized call stack (an array) between my library functions.

This is a `FP` library where piping/composing lots of functions is a common practice. Built-in call stack would trace all calls (contains noise) while I want to neglect internal calls and just record user calls to library and manage trace of internal calls manually as I wish in my custom stack. Seems part of solution is [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/apply) trap but have no idea where to start.

```
// Ramda FP library
// Abbreviate input string: 'some input' -> 'S.I'
const app = R.pipe(R.w, R.x, R.y, R.z)
const output = app('some input')

// Sample actual call stack (including internal calls):
// w -> __w0 -> _t2 -> x -> _x1 -> _x2 -> y -> _y -> z -> _z9

// Desired call stack without internal calls (noise)
// x -> y -> z
```

If I have my own data structure for call stack inside my library then it is possible to produce following output of above example as:

```
pipe:    w      ->      x     ->     y    ->    z
    'some input'    ['s','i']   ['S','I']    'S.I'
```

and in case of error:

```
const output = app('')


// desired output
pipe:  w   ->   x   ->    y   ->    z
      ''       []       Error

Error: Array is empty!
```

**Summary**: I need to implement my own **virtual call stack** which is smart and is used to provide useful data to library users. Considering that in FP libraries currying, partial application... are common use cases makes the problem harder to solve.

Comment: You should include an example use and expected output.

Comment: @user633183: desired output added.

Comment: Even assuming you can modify the call stack somehow, I don't think you can realistically do this because a single traceback might have multiple entry points in to your library. You'll lose a lot of info by truncating all of that. Also proxys cannot be polyfilled so if you go that route you are restricting yourself to modern browsers only. This is kinda the price you pay for grafting FP idioms onto a language that isn't really geared towards them.

Comment: While I don't know that there is a great solution, could you wrap up library code you use to add some `skipStacktrace` symbol to each function?  That might allow you to write your own stacktrace function... somehow.  I'm really not sure of the details, but it seems at least plausible.

Comment: @JaredSmith: Do you think that OOP idioms are closer to the core of JS?  Or something else?  I'd say that the language has many of the important facilities of FP: first-class higher order function, closures, etc.  Of course immutability is more difficult, but I'd say it's pretty close as to which paradigm JS fits better.

Comment: @ScottSauyet JavaScript is generally flexible enough to mold it into whatever you want it to be (as you undoubtedly know better than any of us :). What I meant is that you have to do the work yourself: there's no language-level support other than lambdas and closures. A lot of the functions in your library are in the standard library of other languages.

Comment: "there ain't nothing in CS that can't be solved by another level of indirection!" or IOW, by building your own interpreter. which seems to be what you are describing. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
const audit = fnc => (...args) => {
  console.log(`Before call`, args);
  const result = fnc(...args);
  console.log(`Outcome`, result);
  return result;
}

const myPipe = (...args) => {
  const auditedArgs = map(audit, args);
  return pipe(...auditedArgs);
}


export myPipe;
```

You can check it works by running:

```
myPipe(
  split(' '),
  map(myPipe(
    trim,
    head,
    toUpper)),
  join('.'),
)('some input');
```

[Full example](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-darkness-5nbn4).

Based on that you can wrap everything with error handling and instead of logging things to console - as I do in my example - push function on some sort of stack and return its state on failure.